# Condition variables: wait and notify robustness

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

This is how a condition variable is used in most examples:

```
std::mutex mutex_; //declared somehere
```

Thread 1:

```
if (!pred) {
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
   cv_.wait(lock, [this](){return pred});
}
```

Thread 2:

```
//makes pred true
   cv_.notify_one();
```

It seems that there is a window where, thread 1 checks for pred, finds it to be false and goes on to acquire the lock. However, before it can, thread 2 makes pred true, and notifies the condition variable and moves on. Thread 1 now acquires the lock and is stuck on this condition variable.

How is this case usually handled? Since it is mentioned that taking a lock before a notify is a pessimization and hence should not be done.

I know I can use timeouts but that still isn't a solution to this problem. Does this mean that waiting/notifying on a condition variable, always needs to take a lock if no race condition is to exist?

***EDIT***

There was a comment mentioning that in thread2, we should acquire the same lock before making the predicate 'true'. However, consider the following scenario:

There is a bounded queue with one producer(thread1) and one consumer(thread2). Assume size of queue is 1000. We maintain count of current queue size as atomic int, so that producer and consumer can modify it concurrently without taking locks.
In the above case, the predicate is: Is size of queue < 1000.

Now, if in thread2, I take a lock before modifying this predicate i.e. decrementing count, doesn't it defeat the whole purpose of count being atomic? Also, I want it to be atomic since usual operations (i.e. when queue size < 1000), will be fast.

Comment: There is no race. The `if` is just an extra optimization, you can use `if(true)` and it will still work.

Comment: How is there no race? Before taking a lock, if thread 2 does a notify and moves on, thread 1 will be stuck on the wait

Comment: No, cond is checked again inside wait, while the mutex is locked.

Comment: Can you tell me where this is explicitly mentioned? I thought predicate is only to protect against spurious wakeups, not when performing the wait for the first time. Also, since notify doesn't take a lock before notifying, there is still a window where thread1 checks pred, before waiting, finds it to be false, but before doing the actual wait, thread2 already performs a notify.

Comment: [Right here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) and also in the standard. Again, thread1 does **not** have to che(ck anything before waiting. The check does not change anything except in some cases the thread would not go into wait at all.

Comment: The link you gave doesn't mention that the condition is checked before waiting. It just mentions that "the overload is used to protect against spurious wakeups". Also, what I don't seem to understand is what prevents thread 1 from waiting, *after* thread2 has performed a notify i.e missing the notification from thread2 *just* before going to a wait?

Comment: The answer is in the `while (!pred()) { wait(lock); }`.  The loop condition is evaluated while already holding the mutex.  Of course, the notifying thread has to make the predicate true *before* notifying the waiting thread.

Comment: I see where the confusion stems from. The other thread doesn't take a lock before notifying, but *it must take a lock before modifying the predicate* (and then may release it before notifying). That's the purpose of the lock!

Comment: @n.m. Edited the question to give more context. It is detrimental to take a lock in the given case.

Comment: Please look at the linked example and explain where do you think **it** fails. If it doesn't fail, and your hypothetical scenario does, this means the conditional variable is not the right tool for **your** scenario, or that you are not using it correctly. It doesn't mean there is an inherent design flaw. Bear in mind that a lock that is only used by a single thread is completely useless.

Comment: In your queue scenario, it is necessary to lock on the queue-is-empty and queue-is-full conditions, not on the atomic counter.

Comment: All changes made by a thread *before* an atomic store (using the default sequentially consistent memory model) will be visible to another thread *after* it does an atomic load (again using default memory model) without the need for an additional mutex.  So as I understand your scenario, it seems fine.  It would be easier to reason about if you'd provide concrete code, though.

Comment: That is *not* how a condition variable is used in "most examples". Most examples never *access* (not just change) the predicate unless the mtx is locked. That is the point of the mtx: protect the predicate *entirely*. The cvar itself is just a notify-mechanic. If you want to use atomics for your predicate, fine, but you're not saving anything. The purpose of a cvar+mtx pair is its ability to begin waiting on the cvar-notification *and* release access to the mtx atomically (as far as you know) for someone else to be able to latch the mtx, change the predicate state and invoke a cvar-notify.

Comment: @n.m.: The queue-is-empty and queue-is-full conditions are based on the atomic counter, so locking on them won't help.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Your explanation seems right. The reason why I used an atomic counter is so that thread1 doesn't need to take a mutex while adding elements (and vice versa for thread2). This will slow the "normal" flow (i.e. when the queue is not full). Based on your explanation it seems that condition variables cannot be used with predicates that rely on atomic variables, which does sound right.

Comment: @user1715122 they're somewhat different eggs in different baskets. I understand the desired behavior, but you must also understand that the heart of cvar+mtx programming is to have a concretely-decidable predicate.  For most work-queue-based situations, that predicate is generally one of two plausible states. (1) is there anything in the queue, and (2) is it time to bail this worker-proc. The retrieval of the latter is certain atomic-doable, But the former is usually done under the blanket of mutually exclusive access, which is somewhat the point of the mutex: protect the predicate....

Comment: @user1715122 It sounds like you understand that, though. It may be possible to tailor your code for lockless insertions, but before you kill yourself doing so, it may be worth your time to see if the conventional model is sufficient. it may-well-be, depending on how fast you can get data *on* and *off* the queue, thereby minimizing lock-time. Worth at least a test or two, I would think.

Comment: "are based on the atomic counter" correct. "so locking on them won't help" not so correct.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll see if the atomic counter is providing any tangible benefit, if not, I'll replace it with a regular variable in a lock context.

Comment: A mutex locks code, not data. You have your atomic counter that doesn't need locking on increment and decrement operations. But "queue becomes/ceases to be full/empty" are more complex cases, they involve signalling, not just counter changes, and these cases need locking.